# Why does erode work on a BGR picture, if it only operates with 0 and 1?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Im a very new beginner with python and opencv, and i cannot understand how come the erode function in opencv also works on a BGR picture. I get the understanding the it only works for a binary picture.
I've attached a picture, the left picture has a blue HSV mask, and the right one has added erosion with parameters (kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8).
The 5x5 kernel should make every value 0, unless the whole kernel has 1 in every field, so why does it make it more blue?

I understand why erosion works for a binary picture, but not with colored pictures.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Z6ESuY2
Picture of hsv left, and hsv with erode right.

Comment: nothing's preventing the algorithm from operating on each color plane individually. it doesn't have to be binary either. erosion, lifted to grayscale, is just a `min()` function on the local neighborhood

Comment: It works with grayscale images also. So each channel of the BGR image.  On grayscale, erode is like minimum.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology) or search Google.

Comment: Appreciate the answers. Thank you!